# MapReduce shuffle/sort method

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Somewhat of an odd question, but does anyone know what kind of sort MapReduce uses in the sort portion of shuffle/sort?  I would think merge or insertion (in keeping with the whole MapReduce paradigm), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's Quicksort, afterwards the sorted intermediate outputs get merged together.
Quicksort checks the recursion depth and gives up when it is too deep. If this is the case, Heapsort is used.

Have a look at the Quicksort class:

```
org.apache.hadoop.util.QuickSort
```

You can change the algorithm used via the map.sort.class value in the [hadoop-default.xml](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.19.1/conf/hadoop-default.xml).

Comment: This switch of sort technique is a standard hybrid sorting AFAIK. Its called IntroSort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort