# What sorting algorithm does mapreduce use in Hadoop? Can I change it?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

At first I parsed my .jar file containing the program of WordCount along with input and output destination in the command line. After the completion of my job, I saw the content of my output file: it was sorted automatically alphabetically or sorted by numbers in ascending order. Is there any way to change it internally in hadoop? Which algorithm does it use to sort?

Comment: TeraSort algorithm. 

Reference:http://sortbenchmark.org/YahooHadoop.pdf

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779750/mapreduce-shuffle-sort-method